# What happens if the list instance is replaced during enumeration?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Lets say we got two threads running, the first one is going to be enumerating the list, something like

```
foreach(int a in someList)
{
    //Do something
    //Thread 2 comes in
}
```

and then thread 2 assigns a new instance to "someList"

```
someList = new List<int>();
```

Question1: What will happen to thread1? Will it throw exception or continue to enumerate the old instance?
Question2: Is there a danger of the "old" list getting garbage collected before the enumeration is finished? Since nothing is referencing that old list anymore except the enumerator.

Comment: Write some code and start testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach calls `GetEnumerator` on the `someList` and thus gets an object of type `IEnumerator`. This object remembers the original list and reads elements from it, one by one.

If you now assign new thing to `someList`, then:

- you will only reassign the variable, it will **not destroy** old list and will **not change** the old list
- no exceptions will be thrown since contents of old list are **not changed**
- as long as it exists (->until foreach ends or `break`s), IEnumerator will still remember old list and read from that
- foreach holds IEnumerator, IEnumerator holds old list, nothing will be GC'ed

Proof:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int>{ 1,2,3,4,5};
    foreach(var x in list) // foreach grabs old list and keeps it
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        list = new List<int>{9,9,9}; // replace the whole list
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Above example is singlethreaded and behaves like described. Changing that to multithreaded will not make things worse, because foreach reads the variable and remembers the instance **just once**, so in multithreaded design, even if you don't add locks and leave races, in worst case it will **either** grab old list, or **grab the new list**, but never both.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Question 1: If my memory serves correctly, it'll throw an exception.</s>

Question 2: Perhaps, but that shouldn't matter because an exception should be thrown anyway.

It appears the above is only correct if you're modifying the list, my bad.

Comment: I think you're thinking of a concurrent modification exception, but in this case the list isn't being modified, just the reference.